# Persisting a computed datetime column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have an XML column in a table; I want to "promote" a certain value in that XML as a computed column and index it for faster searching. I have a function that takes in the XML information and outputs the element of interest, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fComputeValue] (@data XML)
RETURNS datetime
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN @data.value('(/Metadata/Value[@Key="StartDate"])[1]', 'datetime')
END
```

However when I try to create the computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomMetadataTable ADD [StartDate] AS ([dbo].[fComputeValue]([CustomMetadataColumn])) PERSISTED
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Computed column
>   'StartDate'
>   in table 'CustomMetadataTable' cannot be
>   persisted because the column is
>   non-deterministic.

It works if I:

- work with varchar, int, double (i.e. other than datetime) values
- remove the PERSISTED keyword (but then I can't create an index on the column)

I should also mention that datetime values are in XSD datetime format.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fComputeValue] (@data XML)
RETURNS varchar(50)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN @data.value('(/Metadata/Value[@Key="StartDate"])[1]', 'varchar(50)')
END
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomMetadataTable ADD [StartDate] AS (convert(datetime,([dbo].[fComputeValue]([CustomMetadataColumn]), 127)) PERSISTED
```

or:

```
return convert(datetime, @data.value('(/Metadata/Value[@Key="StartDate"])[1]', 'varchar(50)'), 127)
```

From books online:

> `CONVERT` is Deterministic unless one
>   of these conditions exists:
>
> Source type is sql_variant.
>
> Target type is sql_variant and its
>   source type is nondeterministic.
>
> Source or target type is datetime or
>   smalldatetime, the other source or
>   target type is a character string, and
>   a nondeterministic style is specified.
>   To be deterministic, the style
>   parameter must be a constant.
>   Additionally, styles less than or
>   equal to 100 are nondeterministic,
>   except for styles 20 and 21. Styles
>   greater than 100 are deterministic,
>   except for styles 106, 107, 109 and
>   113.

It might help if you use `CONVERT` with style `127`

Comment: Thanks!  I had the same problem.  I wonder why 127 works when others don't?

Comment: This is the reason:
"Styles greater than 100 are deterministic, except for styles 106, 107, 109 and 113."

Comment: Instead of changing the ALTER TABLE statement, you can also change the fComputeValue FUNCTION definition: the function can return datetime as the OP wanted it to, if you invoke CONVERT with style 127 in the body/implementation of the function.

Comment: You can find the information about which conversion styles are deterministic on [the CONVERT page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx#languageReferenceRemarksToggle).